# Good practice to pass function in props?

Tags: reactjs

I know that React does diffing of the `this.state`. But when you are in a child component, diff is done on `this.props`. So I was wondering how does the diffing system diff if the value of a `prop` is a function? Is it bad practice, (as in bad for perf or something), if I put a function into the this.props or this.state?

Comment: If you pass to props `function` in child component diff algorithm will triggers  constantly. If you care about this you can implement `shouldComponentUpdate` where you can ignore properties which contains `functions`. Example - https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/32508/, you can experiment with this example, just comment `shouldComponentUpdate`

Comment: Interesting thanks very much @Alexander I'll study that, if you can move that to answer I would love to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass to child component function as a `props` diff algorithm will be constantly triggered. If you care about this case you can implement `shouldComponentUpdate` where you can ignore properties which contains functions.

You can experiment with [`this example`](http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/32508)

Answer (score -1):

Pass the unbound function to the child component, and have the child use an instance method, e.g:

```
class Container extends Component {

    deleteItem(index) {
        actionThatDeletesSomething(index);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <ChildComponent deleteItem={ this.deleteItem } />
        )
    }
}


class ChildComponent extends Component {

    render(){
        return(
            <a onClick={ this.props.deleteItem(index) } />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit more I dont understand :(

Comment: Ah thanks this is interesting, I have to think more on this I dont understand it totally but that insufficiency is on my part. Ill report back after I think about it :)

Comment: @Sagi Medina actually in this example there is no performance gains because you still pass reference to function and this is important for diff algorithm which can't compare difference between two function....